# What does inflection points of a function tell us about the integral of the function?

Tags: calculus

**Context:**

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $4$ with $2$ inflection points. A line is draw through the inflection points and three regions are made.
What inference can you make about these regions?

1. Two regions have equal area;
2. Area of one is equal to sum of other two;
3. area of one is double the sum of other two;
4. area of one region is square of the sum of the other two;

**What I found already**:

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-integration-new/ab-6-5/a/behavior-of-antiderivative-of-f-from-graph-of-f

This articles  tells  that increasing function suggest concave up integral but not sure if that is what I need to solve this problem.

Comment: First of all, I suggest you choose a specific quartic with two points of inflection, and see what the areas of the resulting regions are. Unless you are unlucky, this will tell you which of the four options is the correct one. Then you can try to prove it for a general quartic.

Comment: I tried 
the function I got was $x^4 -x^3\\$;


$f''(x)= 12x^2 - 6x\\$



inflection is at x=.5 and x=0


I think 1. is the correct option 
now what?

Comment: Your chosen polynomial is highly symmetric. That is a recipe for being "unlucky" in a problem like this. Is the equality of areas actually true in general, or is it an artifact of the symmetry?

Comment: urghh this is very frustrating... I can't figure this out at all like where to start even... Some more hints would be appreciated

Comment: @PaulSinclair: We can transform the quartic so that it _is_ symmetrical, without changing the areas of the three regions. See my answer.

Comment: #4 can be eliminated immediately because if you were to measure two of the areas in $m^2$, it would have the remaining area in $m^4$. When you actually graph such a polynomial, you realize that in certain situations two of the areas will disappear while the third remains. #2 and #3 do not allow that. All the remains is figuring out how to prove #1, as TonyK has done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let our quartic be $P(x)=x^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$ (we may suppose after scaling that the coefficient of $x^4$ is $1$). Suppose we add a linear term of the form $ux+v$ to get $Q(x)=x^4+bx^3+cx^2+(d+u)x+(e+v)$. Then the $x$-coordinates of the points of inflection are unchanged (because $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(ux+v)=0$), and the areas of the three regions are unchanged (because the graph has been transformed by a vertical shear transform).

But now we can choose $u$ and $v$ so that $Q(x)=0$ at the two points of inflection.

The points of inflection of $P$ and $Q$ are at $x$-coordinates
$$-\frac{b}{4}\pm\sqrt{9b^2-48c}$$
We now transform the graph by shifting it right, to get the polynomial

$$R(x)=Q(x-b/4)=x^4+Bx^3+Cx^2+Dx+E$$

This transformation preserves the shapes of the three regions, and therefore their areas. And its points of inflection lie on the $x$-axis, symmetrical about the $y$-axis. $R(x)$ can differ from $P(x)$ in all terms except the first, but the areas of the three regions cut off by the line joining the points of inflection are unchanged.

Its points of inflection are at
$$-\frac{B}{4}\pm\sqrt{9B^2-48C}$$
But these points are symmetrical about the $y$-axis. Therefore $B=0$, which means that the points of inflection are $(\pm\alpha,0)$, where $\alpha=\sqrt{-48C}$.

And they lie on the curve $R(x)=0$, so $R(\alpha)=R(-\alpha)$, or

$$\alpha^4+C\alpha^2+D\alpha+E=\alpha^4+C\alpha^2-D\alpha+E$$

which gives us $D=0$.

So now we are left with $R(x)=x^4+Cx^2+E$, which is symmetrical about the $y$-axis. Hence the first and third regions have the same area.

Comment: "But these points are symmetrical about the y-axis. Therefore B=0, which means that the points of inflection are (±α,0), where α=−48C−−−−−√."

What does this statement mean?

Also if you could , some pictures would be nice, I'm finding it hard to visualize this problem

Comment: @DDD4C4U - The points of inflection are given by $-\frac B4\pm\sqrt{9B^2-48C}$. The only way for these two points to be symmetric about the $y$-axis is for the first term to be $0$. Therefore $B = 0$. And when $B = 0$, the expression reduces to $\pm\sqrt{-48C}$. (The points are symmetric about the $y$-axis because he specifically chose transformations to make them so.)

Comment: Why is it a must that this expression should be symmetric again?

Comment: @DDD4C4U: Which expression?

Comment: Like why should the roots of second derivative be symmetric ?/ how did you transform it to become symeteric?

Comment: @DDD4C4U: The mid-point of the two points of inflection of $Q(x)$ is at $x=-b/4$. So I shifted this to the right by $b/4$, to get a polynomial $R(x)$ with the mid-point at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

So much of calculation as shown by @TonyK earlier can be avoided if we assume points of inflexion to be $(-a,0)$ and $(a,0)$ which give

$f''(x)=x^2-a^2$

and consequently

$f(x)=\frac{1}{12}\left(x^4-6a^2x^2+5a^4\right)=\frac{1}{12}\left(x^2-a^2\right)\left(x^2-5a^2\right)$

which is clearly an EVEN function.

To check for areas see the following

$$\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)dx=\frac{8a^5}{15}$$ and $$\int_{a}^{\sqrt5a}\left|f(x)\right|dx=\frac{4a^5}{15}$$