# What can a translation of a polynomial do to bring the equation into a nicer form?

Tags: polynomials, linear-transformations, radicals

I'm very sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm very stressed and would appreciate any advice at all!

I'm trying to write a report (on radicals) and one of the questions I'm being asked just isn't clicking in my brain and I was really hoping someone could reword it maybe, or point me in the right direction of any online resources!

My exam question is:

**"There is a general principle of applying a transformation (generally a translation $y=x-e$ to bring the equation into a nicer form. What can that translation achieve for an equation of higher degree (depressed form)? "**

I don't know if I'm being stupid, but I don't quite understand what's being asked. I'm unsure of the specific importance on the translation $y=x-e$. Is this a commonly used translation to simplify polynomials? Because I just thought that moved the mapping to the right slightly?

I have looked everywhere and came up short so anything at all would be so so appreciated!

(and please be nice I'm one stressy breakdown from never recovering lol)

Comment: I don't know if it will help you, but you might like to look at [this recent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3621870/1508) of mine, which translates a polynomial to good effect.

Comment: How do you depress a cubic?